# Backing out of an full-screen dialog

Tags: android

if I launch a full-screen dialog like such

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
                                       DialogStyleCreator editor = new DialogStyleCreator();
                                       FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                                       transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                                       transaction.add(android.R.id.content, editor).commit();
```

How can I make it so that if I hit the android back arrow (in the top left of the menu) or the back button it closes the dialog instead of going back to the previous activity like in alert dialogs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply put your transaction in stack of fragment manager and override the function of back button

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (Integer.parseInt(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) > 5
        && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
        && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        // Simply pop back your fragment stack here
        return true; 
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   // Simply pop back your fragment stack here
}
```

Comment: You may add the fragment transaction to backstack by transaction.addToBackStack(null);
You may pop back the backstack by
fragmentManager.popBackStack();

Comment: For the back button on top-left corner, simply apply the same things in onclicklistener

Comment: intercepting on back pressed will be the simplest, most straight forward

Answer (score 0):

Since you have added the `DialogFragment` as  `transaction.add(android.R.id.content, editor).commit();` you may not have option to listen the dismiss call back.
 I suggest you to create the `DialogFragment` instance and start it like

```
fm.beginTransaction().add(sampleDialog, "Dialog").commit();
```

and set the call back interface for Activity Back Button Click and call `dismiss();`

Comment: I can't because it ruins the layout